# Conditional probability question with boxes and marbles - confused

Tags: probability, statistics

There are n + 1 boxes labeled from 0,1,2,...,*n*. In each box, there are *n* + 1 marbles. Box 0 has 0 black and *n* + 1 white marbles. Box 1 has 1 black and n white marbles. In general, Box *i* has i black and (*n* + 1 − *i*) white marbles. Pick a box at random, and draw n marbles, so there is one left in the box. Given there are *k* black marbles in the *n* draws,

what is the probability that the one in the box is black?

If *k* = *n*, then the probability is zero, since no box contains *n* + 1 black marbles. If there are [exactly] *k* < *n* black marbles in the *n* draws, then the chosen box must be either box *k* or *k* + 1. I'm having trouble understanding why the chosen box is either *k* or *k* + 1.

Comment: There must have been at least $k$ black marbles in the box, since you drew $k$ marbles.  On the other hand, since there is only one marble left in the box, there can have been at most $k+1$ black marbles in the box.  Hence the box is either $k$ or $k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered in a comment. Another way to put it: There were $k$ black marbles in the box, plus the number of black marbles left. Since there's one marble left in the box, the number of black marbles left is either $0$ or $1$. Thus the number of black marbles was either $k$ or $k+1$. And the number of black marbles is the number of the box.